# Header для скачивания файла

Tags: php

Никак не могу сообразить, какие заголовки послать, чтобы архив приходил не битым и из него нормально извлекались файлы. На данный момент перепробовал много вариантов, один из них такой:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Даже если динамически подставлять mime type, то файл не извлекается из архива.

Есть и такой пример:

```
 $file = '/path/do/filename.txt'; // или любое др расширение
 $filename = 'имя которое увидит юзер.txt'; // расширение тут обязательно
 header ('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
 header ('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 header ('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
 header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
 readfile($file);
 exit();
```

Посоветуйте как быть?

Answer (score 1):

```
function download($filename, $mimetype='application/octet-stream') {
        if (!file_exists($filename)) return 'Файл не найден';

        $from=$to=0; $cr=NULL;

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
                $range=substr($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], '=')+1);
                $from=strtok($range, '-');
                $to=strtok('/'); if ($to>0) $to++;
                if ($to) $to-=$from;
                header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
                $cr='Content-Range: bytes ' . $from . '-' . (($to)?($to . '/' . $to+1):filesize($filename));
        } else  header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok');

        $etag=md5($filename);
        $etag=substr($etag, 0, 8) . '-' . substr($etag, 8, 7) . '-' . substr($etag, 15, 8);
        header('ETag: "' . $etag . '"');

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($filename)-$to+$from));
        if ($cr) header($cr);

        header('Connection: close');
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
        header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('r', filemtime($filename)));
        $f=fopen($filename, 'r');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
        if ($from) fseek($f, $from, SEEK_SET);
        if (!isset($to) or empty($to)) {
                $size=filesize($filename)-$from;
        } else {
                $size=$to;
        }
        $downloaded=0;
        while(!feof($f) and !connection_status() and ($downloaded<$size)) {
                echo fread($f, 512000);
                $downloaded+=512000;
                flush();
        }
        fclose($f);
        return 0;
  }
```

Comment: я так понимаю тут с докачкой файла реализовано?
как то оч сложно получилось

Comment: !   C:\Users\User\Desktop\PayPal_Platform_PHP_SDK_N (1).zip: Unexpected end of archive
вот что выдает, если я использую вашу функцию. по размеру архив скачивается правильно

Comment: А может стоит попробовать хоть на минутку отойти от образа "йя крутой и знаю ПХП", и почитать RFC?